# Python, find a file in the same directory

Tags: python

Let's say I have the files a.py and b.txt in the same directory.  I can't garuntee **where** that directory is, but I know b.txt will be in the same directory as a.py.  a.py needs to access b.txt, how would I go about finding the path to b.txt?  Something like "./b.txt" won't work if the user runs the program from a directory other than the one it's saved in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the location of the main script, even from code that might be running in an imported module, you need to use `sys.argv[0]` rather than `__file__`. (`sys.argv[0]` is always the path to the main script; see http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

If you want the location of the current module, even if it's been imported by some other script, you should use `__file__` as Martin says.

Here's a way to use `sys.argv[0]`:

```
import os, sys
dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
print os.path.join(dirname, "b.txt")
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `__file__` variable:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "b.txt")
```